# Error while importing AppStudio app in Developer Portal in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

[Shows error : "Provided add-in package was not understood. Please, make sure that the file being submitted is a valid Office add-in package."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zxSA.png)

Comment: Could you please make sure that the app package has only 3 files. It should contain only manifest.json, outline and color files.

Comment: Yes zip file contains only this 3 files

Comment: could you please share the manifest at DevCommResponseTeam@microsoft.com?

Comment: Ya ok Im sending my manifest

Answer (score 0):

We checked your manifest, following are the changes that needs to be done in your manifest.

1. Manifest Version is not provided in $schema and manifestVersion
2. entity id "about" and "conversations" are reserved ids, which means users are not supposed to supply tabs with those entity ids in the manifest. And "Name" property should not be specified if you use reserved ids.
3. Either provide a value for property "defaultGroupCapability.meetings" or remove it.

We made below changes to your manifest and were able to import it successfully.

```
>         {
>       "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
>       "version": "1.0.0",
>       "manifestVersion": "1.11",
>       "id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
>       "packageName": "com.chat.demo",
>       "name": {
>         "short": "newServiceOps",
>         "full": "ServiceOps"
>       },
>       "developer": {
>         "name": "motadata",
>         "mpnId": "",
>         "websiteUrl": "https://www.motadata.com",
>         "privacyUrl": "https://www.motadata.com/privacy-policy",
>         "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.motadata.com/terms-of-use"
>       },
>       "description": {
>         "short": "ServiceOps",
>         "full": "ServiceOps virtual agent"
>       },
>       "icons": {
>         "outline": "outline.png",
>         "color": "color.png"
>       },
>       "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
>       "staticTabs": [
>         {
>           "entityId": "conversations",
>           "scopes": [
>             "personal"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "entityId": "about",
>           "scopes": [
>             "personal"
>           ]
>         }
>       ],
>       "bots": [
>         {
>           "botId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
>           "scopes": [
>             "personal",
>             "team",
>             "groupchat"
>           ],
>           "isNotificationOnly": false,
>           "supportsCalling": false,
>           "supportsVideo": false,
>           "supportsFiles": false
>         }
>       ],
>       "validDomains": [],
>       "defaultInstallScope": "team",
>       "defaultGroupCapability": {
>         "team": "bot",
>         "groupchat": "bot"
>       }
>     }
```